# Implementing linked list in php - is it safe construction?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, linked-list

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630969/implement-linked-list-in-php/12954568#12954568) is an implementation of linked list. It's OK, it's working. But there are few lines that bother me (comments inside method are mine):

```
//insertion at the start of linklist
public function insertFirst($data)
{
    $link = new ListNode($data);     // create local variable
    $link->next = $this->firstNode;
    $this->firstNode = &$link;       // and remember the reference to it in $this->firstNode
```

**Edit:**
Let me analyse this method line by line:
L1. We create a local variable: $link. 
L2. Doesn't matter. 
L3. In 'firstNode' property we save the reference to local variable.

OK, all clear. But at the end of this method the local variable ($link) will be destroyed. So in 'firstNode' we have a reference to non-existent variable. The place in memory where $link variable was stored is free now. PHP can store there something new. Isn't it?

Comment: Could you explain why you think it could by safe, or not safe? I'll guide the answers.

Comment: @AnthonyB Naturally. Let me analyse this method line by line:
L1. We create a local variable: $link.
L2. Doesn't matter. 
L3. In 'firstNode' property we save the reference to local variable.

OK, all clear. But at the end of this method the local variable ($link) will be destroyed. So in 'firstNode' we have a reference to non-existent variable. The place in memory where $link variable was stored is free now. PHP can store there something new. Isn't it?

Comment: Please update your question to add your explanation, don't write it as comment. It will be easier for every one to read it.