# How to remove a Node from Singly Linked List PHP

Tags: php, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is below a simple Class to create Singly Link List

```
class Node
{
   public $data;

   public $next;

   public function __construct( $data, $next )
   {
      $this->data = $data;
    
      $this->next = $next;
   }
}
```

I am adding new Node using below...

```
$e = new Node( 2, null );

$d = new Node( 15, $e );

$c = new Node( 9, $d );

$b = new Node( 4, $c );

$a = new Node( 3, $b );
```

When i print $a, it shows

```
Node Object
(
[data] => 3
[next] => Node Object
    (
        [data] => 4
        [next] => Node Object
            (
                [data] => 9
                [next] => Node Object
                    (
                        [data] => 15
                        [next] => Node Object
                            (
                                [data] => 2
                                [next] => 
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

which is correct! so now how do i delete a node based on it's value? such as odd or even?

```
if ( $node->data % 2 == 0 ) {}
```

the final result should be...

```
Node Object
(
[data] => 4
[next] => Node Object
    (
        [data] => 2
        [next] => 
    )

)
```

Comment: There are various implementations of linked lists you can start from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630969/implement-linked-list-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define this method on your `Node` class:

```
   public function filter($callback) {
       $dummy = new Node(null, null);
       $tail = $dummy;
       $node = $this;
       while ($node != null) {
           if ($callback($node->data)) {
               $tail = $tail->next = $node;
           }
           $node = $node->next;
       }
       $tail->next = null;
       return $dummy->next;
   }
```

Then in your main program, you can do this:

```
$z = $a->filter(function ($data) {
    return $data % 2 == 0;
});
```

In your example case, `$z` will represent the list `4->2`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but may i ask how `$dummy` variable data is being changed? You are only assigning `$dummy` to Empty Node but inside while or anywhere you are not adding any value in it... how it's being changed as we are returning it at the end! Thanks, if you can please explain, pardon my lack of experiences!

Comment: `$tail` is initially the same node reference as `$dummy`, and at some point `$tail->next` gets assigned, which means `$dummy->next` gets assigned. After that, `$tail` will reference that next node, and will potentially make that list longer...etc.